# Center a UIButton's title vertically for words longer than its width

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, vertical-alignment

I want to implement a `UIButton` so the title appears centered inside, no matter the length of the text.

The problem I'm facing is that **the button's width** and **the font size need to be of a fixed value** because they need to be consistent with the rest of the UI details. And **I can't truncate the text** either.

I am fine with **splitting words**, but **only when the word that does not fit** the title's width.

Currently it's working fine for 1-line and 2-line texts (with spaces) but **when the title contains one long word without spaces, it centers the first line only** (please see the images attached).

[image]
[image]

I guess I would like to do something like:

```
if (button.currentTitle.length > (buttonWidth/characterWidth)) { //2-line title buttons
    // Do something special to fix the problem
}
```

But I've tried setting all these and non of them worked:

```
[button.titleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[button.titleLabel setBaselineAdjustment:UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignCenters];
[button setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 20, 0)];
button.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
```

Any ideas/suggestions to keep the `titleLabel` vertically centered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **wrap the title by characters**, setting your button's [line break mode](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSParagraphStyle_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSLineBreakMode) to `NSLineBreakByCharWrapping` (by default it wraps at word boundaries), only **when it contains words that do not fit.**

```
if (button.currentTitle.length > (buttonWidth/characterWidth)) { //2-line title buttons

    // Check if title contains long words
    NSArray *words = [button.currentTitle componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    for (NSString *word in words) {
        if (word.length > (buttonWidth/characterWidth)) {
            // Set the line break mode to char wrapping
            button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
            break; // No need to continue :-)
        }
    }

}
```